# See carriage returns in Chrome viewing an xml file

Tags: php, xml, google-chrome, carriage-return

My php script creates an xml file filled with various configuration data.
Sometimes I view the xml file directly using Chrome to speed up troubleshooting.
Chrome doesn't display the carriage returns, even though they are definitely there.

I also tried it with and without inclusion of the unicode hex character code &#xd carriage return. Made no difference.

```
<?php

$xmldom = new DOMDocument();
$xml01 = $xmldom->createElement("body");
$xmldom->appendChild($xml01);

$s.= "-----------------------\n";
$s.= "firstline\nsecondline";
$s.= "\n-----------------------\n";
$s.= "firstline\rsecondline";
$s.= "\n-----------------------\n";
$s.= "firstline\r\nsecondline";
$s.= "\n-----------------------\n";
$s.= "firstline\n\rsecondline";
$s.= "\n-----------------------\n";

$xml02 = $xmldom->createElement("entry", $s);
$xml01->appendChild($xml02);

$xmldom->formatOutput = true;
$xmldom->save("a_trythis.xml");

echo "done";

/*
result:

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <body>
      <entry>-----------------------
    firstline
    secondline
    -----------------------
    firstline&#xD;secondline
    -----------------------
    firstline&#xD;
    secondline
    -----------------------
    firstline
    &#xD;secondline
    -----------------------
    </entry>
    </body>

 */

?>
```

result display in Chrome:

[image]

This isn't a big deal, it would just be nice to see the carriage return when I view the xml in Chrome.

Comment: If you press Ctrl-U, that's a shortcut to view source. Then you'll see \n as end of lines.

Comment: Ahhhhhhaaaa... what I thought was View Source wasn't really View Source. Thanks.